# sort by date in mongoose throwing error for records more than 9

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting

```
Error: too much data for sort() with no index
```

while sorting through ascending date. I only get this exception if the no of records are more than 9. Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong? or any work around?

My sorting syntax is:

```
image.find({reviewed:true },null,{sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, function (err, images){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the documentation here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-Using{{sort%28%29}}withoutanIndex

> You may use sort() to return data in order without an index if the data set to be returned is small (less than 32 megabytes in version 2.0, or less than four megabytes in version 1.8 and earlier). For these cases it is best to use limit() and sort() together.

Is it possible that those 9 documents are actually greater than 32 megabytes? Or, as in previous versions, more than 4 megabytes?

Comment: I dont know the exact length of the records  but can you tell me any mechanism to limit the records to first ten?

Comment: @AliHassan You should be able to just use `limit:10` in your node.js query next to your sort however I do not think this will work since it will only limit the rerturn, the entire result will still be sorted before return, as such the solution would be to add an index there

Comment: @AliHassan In console you could do `db.image.ensureIndex({'submittedDate':-1})` that should give you an index on that field.

Comment: can you please define in more details where I have to or how to I have to use this index?

Comment: `code`
logger.info("Index are",image.ensureIndex({'submittedDate':-1}));

giving me 
`code`
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'ensureIndex'

Comment: @AliHassan Here is the docs on it with examples: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#ensureindex

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Basically, as I have mentioned in my subject that I am using Mongoose so I dont have db object.